# Twitter Bootstrap tablet dimension 1024 not 979 on responsive layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I do not understand why Twitter Bootstrap is considering the tablet size from 768 to 979, and not from 768 to 1024 (iPad). The problem is that if a client requests a custom design for tablet, that tablet design will not be visible on iPad in landscape mode.

Also if I have a content with sidebar (span9 + span3), if the sidebar is "hidden-tablet", the content will not expand, in fact it will have the same size and I have to overwrite bootstraps span dimmensions to achieve the desired layout.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I think the idea here is that in general if someone is requesting a page that is over 980px its more likely that its from a desktop computer than it is from an ipad. Also you could just make your page ipad AND web friendly for those widths :).

If you have to have a different design for landscape ipad and the web, an option would be to do write a bunch of custom css for when the screen is between 980 and 1024px.

```
@media (min-width 980px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  //my custom css for ipad landscape
}
```

2) You are doing it right. All `.hidden-tablet` does is set `display: none;`

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  // ... some other code

  .hidden-tablet {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

It does not do any other type of resizing, so thats on you to do with media queries.

Comment: Ok but if i use the media query between 980 and 1024 pixels and make some custom css style for ipad on landscape, i will have than to remake them for resolutions between 768 and 980 pixels, after the bootstrap recalculates the spans. So for example: span9 will be 870px on desktop sizes (> 979px) and 700 on ipad version (768 -> 979).

Comment: like your styles and media query ranges don't have to correspond exactly to the predefined media query ranges that bootstrap uses. If you want some style to be used for all ipad ranges, just do a media query like `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}`. In other projects I have had to do things like that. Even something random like `@media (max-width: 659px)`